# Python: Displaying Graphics on Android Screen from Desktop Script

Tags: android, python, image, cross-platform

**Skip the first two paragraphs if your not interested in why I'm asking this question.**

Here is the situation: I'm using a Moto Z Play with the Projector Modification, the mod is really cool and allows me to literally project my phone screen onto the wall. I've been writing a personal assistant program that helps me with my daily life I.E. Sorting gmails, reminding me of calendar events, keeping track of anything I want it to remember and reminding me of those things when I've asked it to, and much more. Its basically a personal secretary.

One new feature I just added was a habit tracker. I created a small graphical interface on my phone using Tasker that would email my "assistant" who would then record the habit and create a really cool graph that shows my past habit record as well as using a neural network to predict the next days habit. Only problem is, the graph got really intricate really fast. I want to show a months worth of habits (16 total habits), creating what can be up to a 16 x 31 floating point graph with labels. My laptop screen is just not big enough to display all of that without it just being a mess! I really want to display the graph from my projector mod, the entire wall will definitely be big enough to show all that data.

Ok, now my question (thanks for hanging in there I know that was a lot):
Is there any way that I can display an image on my phone from a Python program without creating a standalone app? Even if my phone needs to be plugged into my computer to stream the data through a cable.

I would use a service like Kivy to create a standalone app, but then it wouldn't be hooked up to my assistant, completely defeating the purpose.

I'm not looking for anything similar to a notification, I really want to draw over the entire screen of my phone. This is something I did with Processing (Java library) a while back, but now I'm using Python because it's more machine learning friendly.

I've looked into a lot of services but nothing seems to be able to do this. Remember that I dont need to send anything back from my phone, simply display an image on the screen until the desktop side program tells it to stop.

Answer (score 0):

Not my expertise but if I would need to do something like that I would make a web-service of the python app using django and go to the url with my phone. Don't know if it help....

Comment: Good idea, that would likely be very easy and would even allow me to access the output from other devices as well.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of "how" or "what", the answer is, you will always need some software running on the Android to capture the stream of data (images) and display it in the screen.

The point is, you don't have to write this software yourself. The obvious example that come to mind is use any DLNA compatible software, VLC for example, and have your python to generate a h264 stream and point VLC to it. Another way would be use some http service from your python and simply load it in the browser.

hope it helps.

Comment: My experience with Processing didn't require any software on my phone interestingly enough... so thanks for the heads up that this wont be the same.
I appreciate the pointer at some tools that might work!